# How Crossjoin two tables in Dax created from Generateseries?

Tags: dax

I want to crossjoin to "table" created with GenererateSeries in a single Expression

```
Table =
VAR TableAnnee =
    GENERATESERIES ( 2010; 2020; 1 )
VAR TableMois =
    GENERATESERIES ( 1; 12; 1 )
RETURN
    CROSSJOIN ( TableAnnee; TableMois )
```

Then I have an error message:

> "CROSSJOIN function does not authorize two columns with the same name: [Value]."

How can I crossjoin `TableAnnee` and `TableMois` without creating two real tables but in one expression in that table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`SELECTCOLUMNS` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectcolumns-function-dax) to give your generated tables appropriate column names. The default column name is `[Value]`, so you need to rename that default to do the crossjoin.

```
Table =
VAR TableAnnee =
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( GENERATESERIES ( 2010; 2020 ); "Year"; [Value] )
VAR TableMois =
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( GENERATESERIES ( 1; 12 ); "Month"; [Value] )
RETURN
    CROSSJOIN ( TableAnnee; TableMois )
```